# Mensuration question about a hoop resting on a staircase

Tags: geometry, circles, rectangles

I came across a question recently:

> A hoop, as shown in the diagram, rests vertically at stair case. Note: AB = 12 cm, and BC = 8 cm. Find the radius of the hoop.
>   Figure (hand-made): [image]

This is a question that I have no clue about. I thought that AB might be the radius but well from the diagram it seems no.

A thorough Google search revealed only one site which requires a login, which I don't want to do.

Can anyone please provide a explanatory answer.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q$ be the center of the circle. Draw $QA$, and draw a horizontal line from $C$. Where this line meets $QA$, call it $J$. Then you should be able to get the answer by working with the triangle, $QJC$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the radius be $r$, the center of the circle $O$, and draw the horizontal radius to the right. Drop (raise?) the perpendicular from $C$ to that radius, and call the intersection point $D$. Now $OCD$ is a right-triangle with hypotenuse $OC = r$, and legs $CD = r-8$ and $DO = 12$ (the center *has* to be directly above $A$).

Answer (score 1):

The line through $A$ and $C$ has slope $8/12=2/3$, so the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ has slope $-3/2$.  It will pass through the center of the circle directly above $A$.  Taking $A$ as the origin, $(0,0)$, the midpoint of $AC$ is $(6,4)$, so the equation of the perpendicular bisector is $(y-4)=(-3/2)(x-6)$, so the center of the circle is at $(0,13)$, and hence the radius of the hoop is $13$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: find three similar triangles.

[image]

Comment: Thank you tomasz. But I am having a bit trouble in finding three similar triangles. There are total of 5 triangles in this figure, but none of them seem to be similar. But wait, what exactly does the term 'similar triangles' mean: similar by area or totally congruent?

Comment: @GaurangTandon: it means that you can get one from the other by scaling and isometries, just like the Wikipedia definition says... Actually, all five are similar, though you need just three to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An analytic solution:

The equation of a circle, radius $R$ with centre at $(h, k)$ is:$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=R^2$$If we take the point A as the origin, then the centre is at $(0, R)$ and the equation reduces to:$$(x)^2+(y-R)^2=R^2$$Note that the point $(12,8)$ lies on the circle and must satisfy the equation.

Comment: Hello User58220, $$144 + 64 + R^2 - 16R = R^2$$. Which means that $$208 = 16R$$, which equals $$206/16 = 13$$, which gives the answer as 13. Did I solve it correctly?